# Pushing an MFMailComposeViewController onto the navigation stack? Not presented modally

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a table view, and in one of the cells, it says "contact".  Upon selecting this cell, I'd like to push in a MFMailComposeViewController.

I can only seem to present this MFMailComposeViewController modally. What is the problem here?

Thanks!

Relevant code frag:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    //*works*//[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    //*broken*//[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

}

The error that I get is:  " *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'
*** Call stack at first throw:"

So it looks like I have a navigationController already, and since MFMailComposeViewController is a subclass of UINavigationController, I'm pushing a navController onto another navController?

I want my UI to be consistent, so I want to push a MFMailComposeViewController onto the nav stack rather than present it modally.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? The view just isn't presented, or you get an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `MFMailComposeViewController` isn't a subclass of `UIViewController` but of `UINavigationController`. `UINavigationController` throws an exception when you're attempting to push a `UINavigationController` or subclass of `UINavigationController` onto an existing stack. Presenting a `UINavigationController` modally is permitted.

Comment: OK, so are you saying that you can't bring up a MFMailComposeViewController when "drilling down" on a tableview cell? By drilling down, I mean you tap a tableview cell, and the next view controller is not presented modally by popping up from the bottom of the screen.  I want the MFMailComposeViewController to slide in from right to left. Surely such a basic thing is supported?

Comment: UINavigationController is designed to manipulate a hierarchy of UIViewController objects. Adding another UINavigationController into an existing navigation stack would have unexpected consequences. Consider the UINavigationBar that UINavigationController provides. If you were to push on a new UINavigationController, which navigation bar should take precedence? I suppose if you really need to push the mail composition view controller you could extract just the UIViewController subclass by using `mailComposeController.topViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple documentation

> To display the view managed by this view controller, you can use any of the standard techniques for displaying view controllers

So what you are trying to do is supposed to work in both cases. Did you have a look at the logs ?

I would have bet your navigationController is nil, because this typically happens when you are using a plain UIViewController (not embedded in a `UINavigationController`, but it you actually present your modal view onto the navigationController, it may not be nil.